# separating a column into lists based on specific values

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a column (`data$event`) with events from ice hockey games.
I would like to create sub lists or columns every time the value `goal` appears and adding every event until the last Faceoff in order to analyze the events leading to a goal.

For example, I would like a code to return the following after going through the data.

```
1 (Face-off, Shot, Shot, Takeaway)
2 (Blocked Shot,Blocked Shot,Takeaway)
```

data:

```
data$event  <- c(
  "Faceoff",
  "Shot",
  "Shot",
  "Takeaway",
  "Goal",
  "Faceoff",
  "Blocked Shot",
  "Blocked Shot",
  "Takeaway",
  "Goal",
  "Face-off"
)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below my approach.
Note that I corrected for the inconsistent spelling of `Face-off` vs `Faceoff`;
are you sure that
`2 (Blocked Shot,Blocked Shot,Takeaway)` shouldn't be `Faceoff, Blocked Shot, Blocked Shot, Takeaway`

```r
library(tidyverse)

data  <- c(
  "Faceoff",
  "Shot",
  "Shot",
  "Takeaway",
  "Goal",
  "Faceoff",
  "Blocked Shot",
  "Blocked Shot",
  "Takeaway",
  "Goal",
  "Faceoff"
) %>% 
  enframe(name=NULL, value="event")

data %>% 
  mutate(indicator=case_when(event=="Faceoff" ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>% 
  mutate(sum_indicator=cumsum(indicator)) %>% 
  group_by(sum_indicator) %>% 
  summarise(events=paste0(event, collapse=", ")) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(events, "Goal")) %>% 
  mutate(events=str_remove(events, ", Goal"))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   sum_indicator events                                       
#>           <dbl> <chr>                                        
#> 1             1 Faceoff, Shot, Shot, Takeaway                
#> 2             2 Faceoff, Blocked Shot, Blocked Shot, Takeaway
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm having a hard time applying the code specifically on a column of a data frame, do you know if I have to transform the data before hand?

Comment: @Thomas in the proposed solution above the name of the dataframe is `data' and the column's name is `event`  as used in your question.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run it on data: "Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "factor". " . I feel like it has something to do with transforming the data frame column into a character vector.. The df column doesn't have quotation marks for each event, maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: @Thomas hm, difficult to say why this happens. Even if the variable 'event' would be a factor, the code should work. Can you isolate in which mutate (which row) triggers the error. Can you execute the code row by row?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
# split event
l <- split(data$event, dplyr::lag(cumsum(data$event == "Goal"),1,0))

# keep only actions to Goal
f <- sapply(l, function(x) x[length(x)] == "Goal")
l <- l[f]

# remove goal
l <- lapply(l, function(x) x[-length(x)])

l

#> $`0`
#> [1] "Faceoff"  "Shot"     "Shot"     "Takeaway"
#> 
#> $`1`
#> [1] "Faceoff"      "Blocked Shot" "Blocked Shot" "Takeaway"
```

---

where `data` is:

```
data <- data.frame(event = c(
 "Faceoff",
 "Shot",
 "Shot",
 "Takeaway",
 "Goal",
 "Faceoff",
 "Blocked Shot",
 "Blocked Shot",
 "Takeaway",
 "Goal",
 "Faceoff"
))
```